# Can't find a solution to "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object `x` not found" when using rpart

Tags: r, rpart

I'm trying to run a relatively simple model in R such as `fitTree<-rpart(Event~ACTIVITY_X+ACTIVITY_Y)`. Here's my code with associated data:

```
> library(data.table)
> library(tree)
> library(rpart)

> #From the file "KNNCollar_#.txt", just select the columns ACTIVITY_X, ACTIVITY_Y, ACTIVITY_Z and Event

> dataraw<-fread("KNNCollar_41365.txt", select = c("ACTIVITY_X","ACTIVITY_Y","Event"),stringsAsFactors = F,header = TRUE)
> dataset <- matrix(NA,nrow=0,ncol=3)

> #Now, delete all rows containg the string "End"

> dataset<-dataraw[!grepl("End", dataraw$Event),]
> head(dataset)
   ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y     Event
1:         19         21 Vigilance
2:         20         14 Vigilance
3:         34         35 Vigilance
4:         18          5 Vigilance
5:         23         27 Vigilance
6:         33         20 Vigilance

> names(dataset)<-c("ACTIVITY_X", "ACTIVITY_Y","Event")
> fitTree<-rpart(Event~ACTIVITY_X+ACTIVITY_Y)
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Event' not found
```

As you can see, I'm gettin the error `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Event' not found`.

Other people in the forum have been asking about this, and I've tried to adjust by converting my dataframe into a matrix, reading it from a `.txt`, using `names` etc. as suggested in other posts.

None of this is working for me. Now my question is if that's just a syntax error or there's a real issue with my code?

Hope somebody can help as any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched the internet for "rpart cran", clicked the https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart link and opened up https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/rpart.pdf. Jumping to page where `rpart` is documented it shows that this function accepts formula. If you are specifying a formula AND your data is in a data.frame, you need to pass in the data.frame using `data` argument. In short:

```
fitTree <- rpart(Event ~ ACTIVITY_X + ACTIVITY_Y, data = dataset)
```

Notice that I added spaces which, arguably, enhances readability.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have to convert your database to `data frame` and mention that database in `rpart` i.e

```
fitTree<-rpart(Event~ACTIVITY_X+ACTIVITY_Y, data = database)
```